# Implementing a basic classic try-catch in Zig

Tags: struct, segmentation-fault, zig

How do I implement the classic `try-catch` error handling in Zig?

For example. How to solve this error and only execute `append` when no error occurs?

```rust
var stmt = self.statement() catch {
    self.synchronize(); // Only execute this when there is an error.
};
self.top_level.statements.append(stmt); // HELP? This should only be executed when no error

// ...
fn synchronize() void {
  // ...implementation
}

fn statement() SomeError!void {
  // ...implementation
}
```

If possible please show a modified version of the above code.

Answer (score 5):

Try an if-else, as follows:

```
if (self.statement()) |stmt| {
   // HELP? This should only be executed when no error
   self.top_level.statements.append(stmt)
} else |error| {
  // Only execute this when there is an error.
  self.synchronize()
}
```

You can learn more about if [in the zig documentation](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#if)